# ORA-00942 parent key not found

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

```
create table Researcher
  (Pid number(7),
   lname varchar2(12),
   fname char(10),
   constraint pkResearcher PRIMARY KEY(Pid));

create table Project
  (ProjId char(10),
   MedicName varchar2(10),
   Purpose varchar2(12),
   Start_date date,
   End_date date,
   PI_Id number (7),
   constraint pkProject PRIMARY KEY(ProjId),
   constraint fkProject FOREIGN KEY (PI_Id) references Researcher);
```

I've recently started learning sql.

I previously inserted a statement:

```
insert into Project
values ('PR001','Medic1','heart','1-SEP-2017','31-JUL-2019','10001');
```

This statement was created but when I tried my next statement:

```
insert into Project
values ('PR005','Medic5','blood','10-JUL-18','31-JAN-20','10102');
```

I encounter the error integrity constraint (FKPROJECT) violated - parent key not found

Comment: You've forgotten to include the question in your post. Please edit your post to add in the question. Also, please update the post with the data that's in the researcher table before you ran your insert statements.

Comment: For future reference it helps to be as accurate as possible when asking a question. ORA-00942 is the code indicating *"table or view does not exist* . The code for integrity constraint violations is ORA-02291.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means that the `pid` 10102 is not present in the table `Researcher` which is defined via `constraint fkProject`.

Insert valid record in the `Researcher` table having `pid=10102` and everything will work fine.

Cheers!!